# PHP for each loop creates unequal array

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to convert the MySQL table into an array using PHP. Each Listing ID in the Image Table has at least one Image ID, however the total number of Image IDs may vary.

Image Table:

```
|Listing ID | Image ID |
|  1234     |     1    |
|  1234     |     2    |
|  1234     |     3    |
|  1235     |     1    |
|  1235     |     2    |
```

Essentially, I would like to transform the Image Table into an array with a key value pair like follows:

```
array([0] 1234 => /FilePath/1234-1::/FilePath/1234-2::/FilePath/1234-3, [1] 1235 => /FilePath/1235-1::/FilePath/1235-2, ...)
```

I've been able to write some code that, for the most part, accomplishes this task. However, there are some issues.

The main issue with my code is that the $lid array and $prod array do not contain the same amount of elements ($prod contains one more element than $lid). This is baffling to me since they are pulling data from the same Image Table and therefore should have the same number of elements.

My code:

```
//Set document path
$target_path = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']). "\mypath\image\uploads\\";
//Query to download all listing IDs in Markers table 
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM image");
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
   $temp[] = $row;
}

foreach($temp as $i=>$v){
    $line = $target_path.$v['L_ListingID']."-".$v['L_ImageID'].".jpg";
    if($temp[$i]['L_ListingID']==$temp[$i+1]['L_ListingID']){
    //appending '::' to each string in the $prod array   
        $prod[] = $line."::";
    }else{
    // * will serve as the delimiter in the $prod array
        $prod[] = $line."*";
    //Add each listing ID into Listing Array 
        $lid[] = $v['L_ListingID'];
    } 
}

//Convert the array into a big string
$bigString = implode("", $prod);

//Chop up the big string into sections delimited by '*' and insert into 'prod' array
$prod = explode("*",$bigString);

//Combine $lid array with $prod array     
$combo = array_combine($lid, $prod);
```

A secondary issue is that PHP returns the following message whenever the foreach loop is run:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 2789 in C:\mypath\getimage.php on line 78

Row 2789 is the last row in the image table, so I think this error notice may be related to the fact that $lid and $prod have difference of the number of elements by 1.

Any suggestions are much appreciated. Also, let me know if you can think of a more efficient way to accomplish this task.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this algorithm, you'll have to make a special case for the last line (this causes the notice "Undefined offset" as Ninsuo indicated).

The following algorithm should build the array you expect:

```
$combo = array();
foreach($temp as $v){
    $line = $target_path.$v['L_ListingID']."-".$v['L_ImageID'].".jpg";
    $key  = $v['L_ListingID'];
    if (array_key_exists($key, $combo)) {
      // Append
      $combo[$key] .= '::' . $line;
    } else {
      // Create key
      $combo[$key] = $line;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For the problem :

> Notice: Undefined offset: 2789 in C:\mypath\getimage.php on line 78

This is because you are doing :

```
if($temp[$i]['L_ListingID']==$temp[$i+1]['L_ListingID']){
```

You require `$i+1` even if your `foreach` is on the last element.

You need to check if that `$i+1` key exists, replace it by :

```
if(array_key_exists($i+1, $temp) && ($temp[$i]['L_ListingID']==$temp[$i+1]['L_ListingID'])){
```

For the "main" problem, your code is too complex. If you begin to shake strings and arrays, there is something wrong. Use only strings or only arrays, but not both at once, this will be harder to maintain.

```
$bigstring = '';
$lid = array()
foreach($temp as $i=>$v){
    $bigstring .= $target_path.$v['L_ListingID']."-".$v['L_ImageID'].".jpg";
    if(array_key_exists($i+1, $temp) && ($temp[$i]['L_ListingID']==$temp[$i+1]['L_ListingID'])) {
        $bigstring .= "::";
    }else{
        $bigstring .= "*";
    }
    if (!in_array($v['L_ListingID'], $lid)) {
      $lid[] = $v['L_ListingID'];
    }
}
```

And a last thing : this is a good practice to initialize your arrays before using array operators on variables.

```
$temp = array();
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
   $temp[] = $row;
}
```

Else, PHP will throw E_NOTICEs.

Comment: This code produces an unequal number of elements between $prod and $lid.